# Can't find a best approach searching patterns

Tags: java, design-patterns

My school gave me the assignment to dig into two packages, one called java.util.jar and the other one is java.util.logging. The assignment was about finding patterns within these packages. 
I have a book available with all the patterns but i don't know where to start looking. Can someone give me some tips about a good approach?

Best regards,

Winston

Answer (score 0):

if you  want to start from beginning then for util package click [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/) .

and `util.jar` is use for Provides classes for reading and writing the JAR (Java ARchive) file format, which is based on the standard ZIP file format with an optional manifest file. The manifest stores meta-information about the JAR file contents and is also used for signing JAR files. 
for jar click [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could start by installing Eclipse (https://www.eclipse.org) and then inspecting various classes inside each of these packages with the Type Hierarchy view.  This will show you how the classes relate via superclasses, subclasses, and interfaces and this might enable you to start spotting some patterns.  You could also look at the class members to spot other patterns. Hopefully this can be a start.

Comment: Thank you, that's what i was doing kinda, but i don't know if netbeans is also good for doing this. It's kinda hard to recognize a pattern. Always when i think i found one, my teachers denies me. :P